# Running python scripts from shared folder

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible for users who don't have python installed to run a python selenium script if all the dependencies are present in a shared folder?

E.g. if I put the whole python folder and its libraries in a shared folder, could users run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's generally not a good idea.
If your users work on Windows machines, you should try [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) or [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/) to create an executable which doesn't need Python to execute.
If they work on a Linux or Mac - they have Python on their machines by default